# Homeomorphism between level sets of $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm asked to say whether, given $$f: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad (x,y,z,w) \mapsto x^2+y^2+z^2-w^2 $$ $f^{-1}(1)$ and $f^{-1}(-1)$ are homeomorphic or not (with the usual induced topology).

Let's start in lower dimension first: one can easily see that, given $$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad (x,y) \mapsto x^2-y^2 $$ the level sets under consideration are hiperbolas, hence a simple $90°$ rotation should realize the homeomorphism. Something like $$\psi: f^{-1}(-1) \rightarrow f^{-1}(1), \quad (x,y) \mapsto (y,-x)$$

[Level sets for n=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYc7Q.png)

Step up: $$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad (x,y,z) \mapsto x^2+y^2-z^2 $$ In this case the level sets are dramatically different: $f^{-1}(1)$ is connected while $f^{-1}(-1)$ is not. No chance to find any homeomorphism.

[Level sets for n=3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNU05.png)

Correct so far? Now, what about the $n=4$ case? The result obtained for $n=3$ is totally intuitive and based on graphs.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: the case $n=3$ provides good hints for $n=4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that $f^{-1}(-1)=\{\,(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mid x_1^2+\ldots+x_{n-1}^2-x_n^2=-1\,\}$ is not connected: Any point in this level set must have non-zero $x_n$-component, and hence we can separate the part with $x_n>0$ from the part with $x_n<0$.

For $n>2$, the level set $f^{-1}(1)=\{\,(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mid x_1^2+\ldots+x_{n-1}^2-x_n^2=1\,\}$ is path-connected:
We can continuosly move to a point with $x_n=0$ along a hyperbola $x_1^2-x_n^2=\text{const}$. That leaves us with a point on the sphere $S^{n-2}\subset \Bbb R^{n-1}$, which is connected for $n>2$.